# dynamic css grid generation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I like to know how I can create this grid in reactJs or vanila javascript?

I have tried to use nth-child but it only works with odd or even numbers or specific child.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twpyu.png)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, this will work for 3x5 but you can Color however you want,
For doing this you need a div style as grid in order to get them in that order.

```js
const createTable = (blue,yellow,red)=>{
  let x = 3;
  let y = 5;
  const grid = document.getElementsByClassName('mygrid')[0]
  for(let i = 0;i<x;i++){
    var div = document.createElement('div')
    div.classList.add('createdDiv')
    grid.appendChild(div)
    for(let z=1;z<y;z++){
     var div = document.createElement('div')
     div.classList.add('createdDiv')
      grid.appendChild(div)
    }
  }
  
  let allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('createdDiv');
  [...allDivs].forEach((el,i)=>{
    if((i+1)%x==1&&(i+1)/x >= y-blue){
      el.classList.toggle('blue')
    }else if( (i+1)%x==2 && ((i+1)/x) >= y-yellow ){
      el.classList.toggle('yellow')
    }else if((i+1)%x==0 && ((i+1)/x)> Math.abs(red-y)){
      el.classList.toggle('red')
    }
      
  })
  
  
}

createTable(4,1,3)
```

```css
.mygrid{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33.3% 33.3% 33.3%;
}

.mygrid > div{
  border:1px solid #666;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:center;
}

.blue{
  background-color:#33f;
}
.yellow{
  background-color:yellow;
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
</div>
```

Comment: Try with my new answer where you can select by number the child you want...

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

```js
document.querySelector(".mygrid > div:nth-child(2)").style.backgroundColor = "red";
document.querySelector(".mygrid > div:nth-child(4)").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

```css
.mygrid{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33.3% 33.3% 33.3%;
}

.mygrid > div{
  border:1px solid #666;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:center;
}

.blue{
  background-color:#33f;
}
.yellow{
  background-color:yellow;
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">

  <div style="grid-column:1/-1;">1</div>
  <div >2</div>
  <div class="">3</div>
  <div class="">4</div>
  <div class="">5</div>
  <div class="">6</div>
  <div class="">7</div>
  <div class="e">8</div>
  <div class="">9</div>
  <div class="">10</div>
  <div class="">11</div>
  <div class="">12</div>
  <div class="">13</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but it needs to be dynamic so column 1 (blue) someone could choose 2 instead of 4. your solution is hardcoding the class